# jquery - Observing an iFrame Body's scroll high and expanding to prevent a scroll bar?

Tags: jquery

i have an iframe which can grow inside of the top window.

I would like to prevent the iframe from having a scroll bar by growing the height of the iframe to as it grows, thus preventing a vertical scrollbar. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access needed iframe elements.

```
iframe = $('#myiFrame');
iframe_document = iframe .contents().find('body').parent(); // this one looks little weird, but i can't think of better solution
iframe_document_height = iframe_document.height();
iframe_height = iframe.height();
```